# How to use a named variable within a function

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, lapply

Assume the following dummy data frame:

```
dt <- data.table(A=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"), 
             B=c("e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f"), 
             C=1:12, 
             D=13:24)
```

I'd like to calculate some stadistics (say, mean and standard deviation) per each numeric column ("C" and "D") and each time grouped by the factor columns c("A"), c("B"), and c("A", "B). In the actual data frame, I have about 40 numeric columns, 10 factor columns that group in different combinations and a large list of statistics I'd like to calculate.
Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054117/how-to-assign-each-element-of-a-list-as-arguments-to-a-function-in-a-loop-in-r) (by @thelatemail) I got from a previous question, I know I can use the code below to deal with factor groupings (by=) using a list:

```
groupList <- list(c("A", "B"), c("A"), c("B"))
out <- vector("list", 3)
out <- lapply(
  groupList,
  function(x) {
    dt[, .(mean=mean(C), sd=sd(C)), by=x]
  }
)
```

Now I'd like to go a step further and create a variable containing a list of the names of numeric columns in the data frame and use the name of that variable within the function above. I came out with the following code but unfortunately, it doesn't work. My idea is to use a loop to extract a value from measureList at each turn and place that value within the mean, sd functions. Any ideas? The loop is how I tend to think of these things but I'll be glad to get rid of it if it makes the code faster or more efficient (particularly because one of the factor columns I have has 90 levels). I'd appreciate any pointer to solve this problem! Thanks.

```
factorList <- list(c("A"), c("B"), c("A", "B"))
measureList <- list(c("C"), c("D"))

out <- vector("list", 2)
for(i in 1:length(measureList)){
  out[[i]] <-lapply(
    factorList,
    function(x) {
      dt[, .(mean=mean(eval(measureList[[i]])), 
             sd=sd(eval(measureList[[i]]))),
         by = x]
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out dplyr? I'm pretty sure this can be done via a simple `group_by() %>% summary()` combo

Comment: Re your first lapply, I think the recently added groupingsets function should help. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48547311/ Regarding the eval thing in the second code chunk, that will make it quite a bit less efficient. See `?GForce` and try running with `DT[, ..., by=..., verbose=TRUE]` to see if optimization is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer` with a vectorized function or use `Map` as shown below:

```
m = function(x,y)dt[, .(mean=mean(get(y)), sd=sd(get(y))), by=x]

c(outer(factorList,measureList,Vectorize(m)))
```

or

```
Map(m,rep(factorList,each=length(measureList)),measureList)
```

EDIT:

TO HAVE THE NAMES:

```
m = function(x,y)setNames(dt[, .(mean(get(y)),sd(get(y))), by=x],
                          c(head(names(dt),length(x)),paste(c("mean","sd"),y,sep="_")))

c(outer(factorList,measureList,Vectorize(m)))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works really well. I'm still new with functions but I was wondering whether it could be possible for the column names in each data frame created to reflect the element of 'measureList' that was computed. Thus, instead of having a general column named 'mean' or 'sd', it could say 'mean_C', 'sd_C' or 'mean_D', 'sd_D' according to each case. Otherwise, the result is a list of data frames all looking alike and hard to tell which comes from computing column C and which one from column D.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the new `groupingsets` function from [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
groupingsets(dt
             , j = lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean(x), sd(x)))
             , by = c('A','B')
             , sets = factorList)[, type := c('mean','sd')][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>       A    B        C        D type
>  1:    a <NA>        2       14 mean
>  2:    a <NA>        1        1   sd
>  3:    b <NA>        5       17 mean
>  4:    b <NA>        1        1   sd
>  5:    c <NA>        8       20 mean
>  6:    c <NA>        1        1   sd
>  7:    d <NA>       11       23 mean
>  8:    d <NA>        1        1   sd
>  9: <NA>    e      3.5     15.5 mean
> 10: <NA>    e 1.870829 1.870829   sd
> 11: <NA>    f      9.5     21.5 mean
> 12: <NA>    f 1.870829 1.870829   sd
> 13:    a    e        2       14 mean
> 14:    a    e        1        1   sd
> 15:    b    e        5       17 mean
> 16:    b    e        1        1   sd
> 17:    c    f        8       20 mean
> 18:    c    f        1        1   sd
> 19:    d    f       11       23 mean
> 20:    d    f        1        1   sd
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This uses `dplyr` and `purrr`, but I think it works.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

combos <- expand.grid(factorList, measureList)
map2(combos[, 1],
     combos[, 2],
     ~ dt %>% group_by_at(.x) %>% summarize_at(.y, funs(mean, sd)))
```